# Android ImageReader YUV 420 888 Repeating Data

Tags: android, opencv

I am trying to convert an `Image` received from `ImageReader` using the Camera 2 API to a OpenCV matrix and display it on screen using `CameraBridgeViewBase`, more specifically the function `deliverAndDrawFrame`. The `ImageFormat` for the reader is `YUV_420_888`, which, as far as I understand, has a Y plane with grayscale values for each pixel, and a U plane that has U/V every other with 1 for every 4 pixels. However, when I try to display this image it appears as if the image is repeating and is rotated 90 degrees. The code below is supposed to put the YUV data into a OpenCV matrix (just grayscale for now, not rgba):

```
/**
 * Takes an {@link Image} in the {@link ImageFormat#YUV_420_888} and puts it into a provided {@link Mat} in rgba format.
 *
 * @param yuvImage {@link Image} in the {@link ImageFormat#YUV_420_888} format.
 */
public static void yuv420888imageToRgbaMat(final Image yuvImage, final Mat rgbaMat) {

    final Image.Plane
            Yp     = yuvImage.getPlanes()[0],
            UandVp = yuvImage.getPlanes()[1];

    final ByteBuffer
            Ybb     = Yp    .getBuffer(),
            UandVbb = UandVp.getBuffer();

    Ybb    .get(mYdata    , 0, 480*640        );
    UandVbb.get(mUandVData, 0, 480*640 / 2 - 8);

    for (int i = 0; i < 640*480; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            mRawRGBAFrameData[i + 640*480*j] = mYdata[i];
        }
        mRawRGBAFrameData[i*4  ] = mYdata[i];
        mRawRGBAFrameData[i*4+1] = mYdata[i];
        mRawRGBAFrameData[i*4+2] = mYdata[i];
        mRawRGBAFrameData[i*4+3] = -1;
    }
}
```

Here is my code for the OpenCV frame:

```
private class CameraFrame implements CvCameraViewFrame {

    private Mat mRgba;

    @Override
    public Mat gray() {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Mat rgba() {

        mRgbaMat.put(0, 0, mRawRGBAFrameData);

        return mRgba;
    }

    public CameraFrame(final Mat rgba) {

        super();

        mRgba = rgba;
    }
}
```

The code for receiving drawing the frame:

```
private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {

        final Image yuvImage = reader.acquireLatestImage();

        yuv420888imageToRgbaMat(yuvImage, mRgbaMat);

        deliverAndDrawFrame(mFrame);

        yuvImage.close();
    }
};
```

And, this is the code for making the image reader:

```
mRgbaMat = new Mat(mFrameHeight, mFrameWidth, CvType.CV_8UC4);

mFrame = new CameraFrame(mRgbaMat);

mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(mFrameWidth, mFrameHeight, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 1);

mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(mOnImageAvailableListener, mBackgroundHandler);

AllocateCache();
```

This is the initialization of the arrays:

```
protected static byte[] mRawRGBAFrameData = new byte[640*480*4], mYdata = new byte[640*480], mUandVData = new byte[640*480 / 2];
```

Notes: `mFrameWidth` is 480 and `mFrameHeight` is 640. One weird thing is that the height and width for `ImageReader` and the `Image` received from it have inverted dimensions.

Here is the image with the code above: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcdzf.png

Here is the image with this instead in `yuv420888imageToRgbaMat` https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2MOI.png

```
for (int i = 0; i < 640*480; i++) {
    mRawRGBAFrameData[i] = mYdata[i];
}
```

We can see that data is repeating in the Y frame and for some reason this gives an actual good looking image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem of trying to use OpenCV with the Camera 2 API, I have come up with a solution. The first thing that I discovered was the fact that there is padding in the `ByteBuffer` that the `ImageReader` supplies, so this can cause distortion in the output if you do not account for it. Another thing that I chose do to was to create my own `SurfaceView` and draw to it using a `Bitmap` instead of using `CameraViewBase`, and so far it has worked out great. OpenCV has a function `Util.matToBitmap` that takes a BGR matrix and converts it to an android `Bitmap`, so that has been useful. I obtain the BGR matrix by putting information from the first two `Image.Plane`s supplied by the `ImageReader` into an OpenCV one channel matrix that is formatted as YUV 420, and using `Imgproc.cvtColor` with `Imgproc.COLOR_YUV420p2BGR`. The important thing to know is that the Y plane of the image has full pixels, but the second UV plane has interleaved pixels that map one to four Y pixels, so the total length of the UV plane is half of the Y plane. See [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/0/0d/Yuv420.svg/1200px-Yuv420.svg.png). Anyways, here is some code:

Initialization of matrices

```
m_BGRMat = new Mat(Constants.VISION_IMAGE_HEIGHT, Constants.VISION_IMAGE_WIDTH, CvType.CV_8UC3);
m_Yuv420FrameMat = new Mat(Constants.VISION_IMAGE_HEIGHT * 3 / 2, Constants.VISION_IMAGE_WIDTH, CvType.CV_8UC1);
```

Every frame:

```
// Convert image to YUV 420 matrix
ImageUtils.imageToMat(image, m_Yuv420FrameMat, m_RawFrameData, m_RawFrameRowData);
// Convert YUV matrix to BGR matrix
Imgproc.cvtColor(m_Yuv420FrameMat, m_BGRMat, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV420p2BGR);
// Flip width and height then mirror vertically
Core.transpose(m_BGRMat, m_BGRMat);
Core.flip(m_BGRMat, m_BGRMat, 0);
// Draw to Surface View
m_PreviewView.drawImageMat(m_BGRMat);
```

Here is the conversion to YUV 420 matrix:

```
/**
 * Takes an Android {@link Image} in the {@link ImageFormat#YUV_420_888} format and returns an OpenCV {@link Mat}.
 *
 * @param image {@link Image} in the {@link ImageFormat#YUV_420_888} format
 */
public static void imageToMat(final Image image, final Mat mat, byte[] data, byte[] rowData) {
    ByteBuffer buffer;
    int rowStride, pixelStride, width = image.getWidth(), height = image.getHeight(), offset = 0;
    Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
    if (data == null || data.length != width * height) data = new byte[width * height * ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888) / 8];
    if (rowData == null || rowData.length != planes[0].getRowStride()) rowData = new byte[planes[0].getRowStride()];
    for (int i = 0; i < planes.length; i++) {
        buffer = planes[i].getBuffer();
        rowStride = planes[i].getRowStride();
        pixelStride = planes[i].getPixelStride();
        int
            w = (i == 0) ? width : width / 2,
            h = (i == 0) ? height : height / 2;
        for (int row = 0; row < h; row++) {
            int bytesPerPixel = ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888) / 8;
            if (pixelStride == bytesPerPixel) {
                int length = w * bytesPerPixel;
                buffer.get(data, offset, length);
                // Advance buffer the remainder of the row stride, unless on the last row.
                // Otherwise, this will throw an IllegalArgumentException because the buffer
                // doesn't include the last padding.
                if (h - row != 1)
                    buffer.position(buffer.position() + rowStride - length);
                offset += length;
            } else {
                // On the last row only read the width of the image minus the pixel stride
                // plus one. Otherwise, this will throw a BufferUnderflowException because the
                // buffer doesn't include the last padding.
                if (h - row == 1)
                    buffer.get(rowData, 0, width - pixelStride + 1);
                else
                    buffer.get(rowData, 0, rowStride);
                for (int col = 0; col < w; col++)
                    data[offset++] = rowData[col * pixelStride];
            }
        }
    }
    mat.put(0, 0, data);
}
```

And finally, drawing

```
/**
 * Given an {@link Mat} that represents a BGR image, draw it on the surface canvas.
 * use the OpenCV helper function {@link Utils#matToBitmap(Mat, Bitmap)} to create a {@link Bitmap}.
 *
 * @param bgrMat BGR frame {@link Mat}
 */
public void drawImageMat(final Mat bgrMat) {
    if (m_HolderReady) {
        // Create bitmap from BGR matrix
        Utils.matToBitmap(bgrMat, m_Bitmap);
        // Obtain the canvas and draw the bitmap on top of it
        final SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
        final Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawBitmap(m_Bitmap, null, new Rect(0, 0, m_HolderWidth, m_HolderHeight), null);
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}
```

This way works, but I imagine the best way to do it is to set up an OpenGL rendering context and write some sort of simple shader to display the matrix.

Comment: I think there is a problem on the this line`Core.flip(m_BGRMat, m_BGRMat, 0);` the image looks upside down so I changed it to `Core.flip(m_BGRMat, m_BGRMat, 1);` and also `COLOR_YUV420p2BGR` to `COLOR_YUV420p2RGB` for jpeg conversion.